# How do I hyperlink an image in my Outlook2003 signature?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, email-signature

I have my company logo in my Outlook2003 signature and I was wondering how can I turn that image in to a hyperlink, so it links to my company's website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use some simple HTML to do so:

```
<a href="http://www.yourfavoritelink.com"><img
src="http://yourwebserver.com/pictures/picturename.jpg" alt="picture name"
/></a>
```

Comment: This is a good solution and a very correct one, but is there any point and click method of doing this? It's not just for me, but also for non-savvy users in the office. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Not really, BioX wrote the solution. For the user, send an email with screenshot, that should help them.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a way to do this in Microsoft 2003 without writing HTML.  If you have already created your signature with your logo (pic) in Tools/Options/Mail Formats/Signatures.  Select New as if you are going to send an email.  Choose options in the main menu, go to General Tab, and select email options at the bottom of that tab.  If you haven't already created your signature, you can create it here.  Select the logo (pic) and then click on the hyperlink icon far right next to the picture icon which is next to the font/text icons.  Type in your http location and save.  Hope this was helpful for you.